# environmental variables in bosh deployment

Tags: cf-bosh, bosh

I would like for a job `J` from a release `R` in a bosh deployment to start with a certain environmental variable `E` set, which is not available in the job's `properties` for configuration

Can this be specified in the deployment file or when calling the `bosh` cli?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am pretty sure this is not possible. BOSH does not understand environment variables. Instead, it executes an ERB template with the properties configured in the manifest. For example in [this job template](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/log-cache-release/blob/92c687c1d9a2de843ccb0d4157d8bb1d6b0b7d9f/jobs/log-cache/templates/bpm.yml.erb) from log-cache is executed with the properties from [a manifest](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/1b2367f37cea2dffa1ab35d5935c08937096bc72/cf-deployment.yml#L1452-L1462) along with defaults from the [job spec](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/log-cache-release/blob/92c687c1d9a2de843ccb0d4157d8bb1d6b0b7d9f/jobs/log-cache/spec#L30-L72).

If you need to have a particular environment variable set for testing/development, you can `bosh ssh` on to an instance where you are going to run the job and then mutate the generated file. Given the CF deployment example, `bosh ssh doppler/0` and then modify the generated `bpm.yml` in /var/vcap/jobs/log-cache/config/bpm.yml. This is a workaround for debugging and development, if you need to set a field in a manifest reach out to the release author and open an issue or PR the ability to set environment variable as a property by adding it to the job spec.

(note the versions used in the example are just from HEAD and may not actually work)